# Gnome automatically installs when installing OpenBox

Tags: server, gnome, lightdm

I decided to install OpenBox on Ubuntu Server. I installed it using `sudo apt install openbox obmenu obconf lightdm lxterminal firefox`. After a reboot, I logged in and was taken to Gnome. I had to switch to Openbox from lightdm. My question is, how do I uninstall Gnome?

EDIT: I am running Ubuntu 19.10, I didn't check what packages get installed with LightDM

Comment: When running the `sudo apt install …` command, did you check to see what exactly was being installed along with `lightdm`? And I'm not sure that Firefox will run without a desktop environment.

Comment: You haven't said what release you are talking about.  I note `lxterminal` which historically was maintained by the Lubuntu team, but Lubuntu having switched to `qterminal` for the last three releases, `lxterminal` may not be the wisest choice...  I won't look at GNOME as I don't know you release (which matters due to changes..)

Comment: @guiverc I edited the question to add the missing info(19.10). Sorry for the late response ,I didn't know you could tag commenters

Answer (score 0):

Looks like lightdm is responsible for installing Gnome.